# Gnome 3 classic on Ubuntu 12.04: how to get application shortcuts

Tags: 12.04, menu, gnome-classic

Since several weeks I left Unity for what it was, installed Gnome 3, and have been using the classic option. Back in the days of Gnome2 I had a bunch of shortcuts in the top menu bar, for all the apps that I opened daily, like Firefox, the terminal, Eclipse etc. Now I see "Applications" and "Places", then nothing, then the tray icons for mail, connection, date/time etc.

Although I can open any application with the applications menu, I would like to have those shortcuts back. Is that possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just discovered that it's really easy. Open the applications menu and lookup the app you need. Click and drag it to the top panel and there it is!

NB: Moving and deleting shortcuts is possible by pressing the Windows + left Alt key and rightclicking the icon.